# How do I display the index of each value in the array along with the value?

Tags: java

I would like to know how to system print the index of each value in the array along with the value.

Here is the code:

```
// Create the array data
double[] data;
data = new double[10];

// Store values in data
data[0] = 19.95;
data[1] = 23.95;
data[2] = 24.95;
data[3] = 18.95;
data[4] = 29.95;
data[5] = 19.95;
data[6] = 20.00;
data[7] = 22.99;
data[8] = 24.95;
data[9] = 19.95;

// Display the values in data
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println(data[i]);
```

Comment: `System.out.println(i);`? Or `System.out.println(i+" "+data[i]);`?

Comment: You'll need to convert from both double and int to String. This can be as trivial as `"" + i` or using a String.format

Comment: `i` - an index, `array[i]` - a value by index

Answer (score 1):

Simply append to String

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + ", "data[i]);
}
```

Comment: `String.format("%d, %f", i, data[i])` would be more readable to me

Comment: yeah @AndrewTobilko but as he seems to be a noob you'll have to explain properly

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + ": "+data[i]);
}
```

The output would be like this :
0: 19.95 
1: 23.95
2: 24.95
3: 18.95
4: 29.95
....

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with tiny edit:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the array data
        double[] data;
        data = new double[10];

        // Store values in data
        data[0] = 19.95;
        data[1] = 23.95;
        data[2] = 24.95;
        data[3] = 18.95;
        data[4] = 29.95;
        data[5] = 19.95;
        data[6] = 20.00;
        data[7] = 22.99;
        data[8] = 24.95;
        data[9] = 19.95;

        // Display the values in data
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Index " + i + ": " + data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In Java you can concatenate strings using the `+` operator.

Another easy example would be:

```
String name = "Joseph";
System.out.println("Hello " + name);
```

The output would be `"Hello Joseph"`